# Subcollections in firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, saas

I am structuring my Firestore database for a SaaS and I thought this structure:

```
user1

-table1

--subcollection

---data


-table2

--Subcollection

---data

-tabe3

--subcollection

---row

---data

----subcollection

-----row

------data

------data


user2

-table1

--subcollection

---data

-table2

--Subcollection

---data

etc.
```

When a person registers, a collection will be created for that user and I will use subcollections for tables and save information without having a collection with id for each user.

My questions are:

How many subcollection can i use?, affect my database performance?

In this structure i have to use many subcollections.

Is good use this structure? or is better use a collections and use unique ids for users?

For example:

```
table1


-row

--data

---id (user)

---data...



table2

-row

--data

---id (user)

---data...

etc.
```

And like that, i don't have to use subcollections all the time.

Thak you for you support.

Comment: It would have been more useful if you have added those schemas as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the second options is better solution. Because Large nested collection is not good idea. Large Nested collection will be very slow when you get data.
And you can use cloud function trigger on the user created event.

```
table1

---id (user)

---data...

table2

---id (user)

---data...
```

Comment: "Large Nested collection will be very slow when you get data" While there are good reasons for using subcollections, the performance of data retrieval should not be one of them, as the performance of data retrieval does not depend on the amount of data in the collection.

Comment: So, there exists a problem if i use nested subcollections? i read this page https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data and only says that the limitation is that the dificult to eliminate subCollection but the users not have the possibility that eliminate subcollections and this link https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/an2xqp/is_anybody_using_subcollections_in_firestore/efs6b88?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x the user says that is good because the other users not need to interact with others like a SaaS but is feasible to use root collections for users or payments